# MFmailcomposer 's send button is not disabled...?

Tags: iphone

i am using MFMailcomposer .send button is disabled when "To: " field is empty in simulator.
but in device when i run that same application , send button is not disabled...i clicked,
"the mail has sent"  result has been shown..any help?

Answer (score 0):

In any app I've used with the MailComposer screen the send button is disabled until an address is entered. Looking through the documentation I don't see a way to change the behavior in any way.